# Batch script to rename filename based on parent folder name

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, replace, filenames, rename

I'm publishing auto generated content to random language folders. Each folder contains one .jpg file.

The name of the .jpg file is always something like file_1_EN.jpg or file_2_EN.jpg.

What I want to do is replace the _EN in the filename with certain text which is based on the folders name the file is published in.

So, for example, when I publish my content to ..\German\ I want _EN to be replaced with _DE, but when I publish my content to ..\French I want _EN to be replaced with _FR.

I've looked around but couldn't find an answer on this specific question.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend you to use VBScript for this task instead of batch file, here is the code that would do the job.

1 part of the code is a function that will return the abbreviation for the folder name, i included the examples that you posted in your question, you will need to add to the function your other folder names & the return abbreviation for each folder name.

Replace `c:\NameOfDirOfAllFolders` with the actual path of the directory where all these folders are located.

```
Dim FSO, FS, Fldr, Fl, Abbrev
Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FS = FSO.GetFolder("c:\NameOfDirOfAllFolders").SubFolders
For Each Fldr In FS
    Abbrev = GetAbbrev(Fldr.Name)
    For Each Fl In Fldr.Files
        Fl.Name = Replace(Fl.Name, "_EN", "_" & Abbrev)
    Next
Next

Function GetAbbrev(FolderName)
    Select Case FolderName
        Case "English"
            GetAbbrev = "EN"
        Case "German"
            GetAbbrev = "DE"
        Case "French"
            GetAbbrev = "FR"
        Case Else
            GetAbbrev = "UNKNOWN"
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately the VBScript doesn't work as it used to. Each time I run it I receive the following error:
`Line:7
Char:9
Error: File already exists
Code: 800A003A
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtine error.`

I've tried to tweak things myself but didn't found a solution. Any idea what went wrong?